# openshift synchronize cartridges between brokers and nodes

Tags: openshift-enterprise, openshift-cartridge

We removed a cartridge and this has destabilized our OpenShift installation.

I can create apps with several of the carts, but all of our tomcat carts are basically dead. When I run the below, I get 422:

```
curl -sL -w "%{http_code}\\n" -k -X POST https://localhost/broker/rest/domains/domain/applications --user "u:p" --data "name=abc&cartridge=testtomcat-1.0&scale=true&gear_profile=small"
```

I have cleared cache, restarted everything (tc, watchman, openshift*, everything). What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out. Openshift will not install cartridges older than the version that was deleted or deactivated. The steps to fix are:

1. Go onto one node - move out all the directories that make up the cartridge to /tmp, leaving the earliest version of the cartridge
2. Do mcollective restart
3. Go onto the broker and import / activate from that node
4. Move the next oldest cartridge to the correct cartridge directory and repeat steps #2 and #3 until you have added back all the cartridges
5. Activate all cartridges